# Can't install byte-buddy-agent on java 9

Tags: byte-buddy, java-9

Byte buddy says that it works with java 9, there is even code for it: `ByteBuddyAgent.install(ForJigsawVm.INSTANCE)`
I use simple `ByteBuddyAgent.install()` that should check all possibilities (including java 9/jigsaw), but it fails.

I'm doing something wrong? Or it doesn't support java 9 yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support for Java 9 is still experimental but the recent versions of Byte Buddy support attachment on recent *ea* builds of Java 9:

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
```

Make sure that you are:

1. Running a recent version of Byte Buddy.
2. Running a recent version of Java 9.

Do however note that Byte Buddy cannot yet process Java 9 class files due to ASM not supporting it. If you require it, use the *byte-buddy-dep* package and explicitly add a dependency to ASM in version *6.0_ALPHA*. Doing so, allows you to use Byte Buddy on Java 9 with close to no limitations (I am still evening out some edges).